# Query variable of 4 possible types

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Typescript in my node server suggests four possible types of query:

```
string | QueryString.ParsedQs | string[] | QueryString.ParsedQs[]
```

How can I avoid that? I know there's a possible way of ignoring/parsing these types as it's the first time I receive it but I have no idea how to achieve that.

```
Argument of type 'string | ParsedQs | string[] | ParsedQs[]' is not assignable to parameter of type string.
```

Comment: Please include an example of code that produces the error. It is unclear from the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with Express User.

I suggest you to override these types inside the file you calling them.

Example:

```
interface ExpressUser {
  email: string;
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
  password: string;
  user_id: number;
}


declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface User extends ExpressUser { }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it can be a solution somehow. Actually, I have had an obsolete version of typegoose with out of date types. That was the reason why it wrongly passed the type :)